# Remove "further information" fields from Wordpress profiles

Tags: wordpress

I have been trying for a while to remove the "further information" section from the user profile field in wp. Every-time i go in to edit a users information it validates these input and marks them as required.

I have tried this approach to see if its something within this array:

```
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'update_contact_methods',10,1);

function update_contact_methods( $contactmethods ) {
    print_r($contactmethods);

    return $contactmethods;
}
```

This returns an empty array.

I have also found a few references to jQuery. But removing the element manually from the page through chrome dev tools still triggers the validation.

[image]

Any-thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: It turns out this has something to do with AFC which i need to look into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out it was events manager pro, under `Admin -> Events -> Forms Editor -> User Fields`.

A bit annoying but works fine once you find it.